# Testing CUSTOMDATA() in Power BI desktop or service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there any way to simulate a value of CUSTOMDATA() in Power BI service or desktop?

The goal here is to test implementation of CUSTOMDATA() usage within a report, independently of the generation of the embed token.

Comment: got a similar problem and what's worst I didn't manage to to use it even after a full MS sample of Embedded PowerBI (appownsdata). By any chance have you been able to make progress ?

Comment: No, the only way I was able to test was generating embed tokens with customData values and using them with the report in Developer Playground.